# What grants are needed to DESCRIBE a Snowflake-object?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The DESCRIBE function of Snowflake can be applied to many objects, like users, warehouses or databases (https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/desc.html).

I cannot find what grants are required to execute DESCRIBE. From experiments, I figured out a few things:
- In most cases, only the OWNER of an object is allowed to DESCRIBE that object
- Exception: DESCRIBE DATABASE is allowed to be executed by non-owners
- (Exception: DESCRIBE SCHEMA fails when the schema holds an external table, but this is probably just not implemented)

I cannot find in the documentation what the general grants are in order to perform DESCRIBE. My test seem to suggest that there is no general rule, but I would be very happy of somebody can prove me wrong :-)

Answer (score 1):

From my experiments, all of the basic objects that lie under a schema, such as *Tables, Procedures and Functions, File Formats, Stages*, etc. will permit `DESCRIBE` commands if ***any*** of its privilege types is granted to the accessor. This implicit behaviour may be why it is not specially called-out in Snowflake's [access control documentation page](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-control-privileges.html#table-privileges).

For almost all other types of objects, the `MONITOR` privilege is necessary to permit `DESCRIBE` commands. Quoting a relevant part [from the documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-control-privileges.html#database-privileges):

> `MONITOR`
>
> *Resource Monitor , Warehouse , Database , Schema, Task*
>
> Grants ability to **see details within an object** (e.g. queries and usage within a warehouse).

Comment: Good find Harsh! I discovered that for Storage Integration objects, there is only a USAGE and OWNER privilege. As a consequence, only the OWNER has the ability to DESCRIBE this type of object.